# Excel sub to fill out a table averaging data of another sheet

Tags: vba, excel, average

I am having issues to get data from several time stamps into usable data.

I am trying to fill out a table which the first of every column is a month (January --> December) and the first of every row is an hour of day (00 --> 23).

The table is to be filled out by averaging data from another sheet which consists of a timestamp (i.e. 2011-01-01 0:00) and an amount (i.e. XXXX.XX).

My current logic is this:

1. Get Cell Number (i.e. B2)
2. Get Hour and Month allocated to cell (i.e. 00 and January)
3. Loop through data and Average data of said month and hour from other sheet excluding weekend days

Can anyone help me figure out the coding for this?

Comment: To improve your chances of getting an answer Please visit Help center on [ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Need sample data and also what you have tried so far.  You can achive the same using Countifs and sumifs.

So a given cells will be sumifs/countifs to get the average time for the given hour and for the given month.

To know more you can use excel help for the given formulas.